# Openstack Juno Sahara Data Processing on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, juju, openstack

http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/sahara-install.html seems to imply that there are no Ubuntu packages for Sahara, and I am wondering if, recently, there has been a Juju Charm, apt-get repo or other alternatives for Sahara installations, under 14.04.
Cheers,
Edit 1: Workaround for now is to:

1. apt-get install python-pip
2. pip install sahara
3. Follow setup in http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/sahara-install.html

At this point, you should be able to issue sahara-db-manage ..., and go through "Data processing" submenu in Horizon. (If you wish, you can make a .conf to control sahara as a service.) Other things to watch out for:

1. Had to resinstall a few olso package. See
   https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/54853/no-module-named-config-installing-sahara-juno-on-ubuntu-1404/
   for detail
2. I initially had apt-get installed python-saharaclient and
   python-saharaclient-doc, and right now I am not sure if it is needed,
   i.e. pip install sahara may be enough.